# ionic serve infinite reloading when no files changed

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

**Current Behavior**

When testing my ionic app’s build with the `ionic serve` command (after the initial compile and load of the app on the dev server) something is causing the app to recompile (similar to live reload) even though no files were changed.  This seems to continue infinitely.

Sample Log:

```
Date: 2021-06-09T16:49:20.399Z - Hash: 6ad0d92ddcbced3a4d48
[ng] 133 unchanged chunks
[ng] Time: 2112ms
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /common.js.map
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /5.js.map
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /referral-referral-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /leaderboard-board-board-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /tabs-tabs-module.js.map
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /GothamRounded-Bold.otf
[ng] Date: 2021-06-09T16:49:23.177Z - Hash: 6ad0d92ddcbced3a4d48
[ng] 133 unchanged chunks
[ng] Time: 1980ms
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /leaderboard-board-board-module.js.map
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /default~onboarding-phone-verify-phone-verify-module~profile-profile-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /profile-profile-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /community-community-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /home-home-module.js.map
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /wallet-wallet-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /profile-settings-settings-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /waitlist-waitlist-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /marketplace-marketplace-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /runtime.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /polyfills.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /styles.js
[ng] Date: 2021-06-09T16:49:25.972Z - Hash: 6ad0d92ddcbced3a4d48
[ng] 133 unchanged chunks
[ng] Time: 2137ms
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /main.js.map
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /vendor.js.map
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /common.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /5.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /tabs-tabs-module.js
[ng] Date: 2021-06-09T16:49:28.928Z - Hash: 6ad0d92ddcbced3a4d48
[ng] 133 unchanged chunks
[ng] Time: 2313ms
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /common.js.map
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /referral-referral-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /leaderboard-board-board-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /home-home-module.js
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /tabs-tabs-module.js.map
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /5.js.map
[ng] Date: 2021-06-09T16:49:32.628Z - Hash: 6ad0d92ddcbced3a4d48
[ng] 133 unchanged chunks
```

**Expected behavior**

The app to only recompile when I change a file

**What have I tried**

- The behavior still happens even if I include the `--no-live-reload` flag
- The behavior still happens if I run the command in a terminal with VSCode closed
- Restarted the computer
- updated chrome
- reverted to an earlier version of the app
- reinstalled npm packages

**Technical Details**

- OS: MacOS Big Sur
- npm: 6.14.8
- NodeJS: 12.19.0
- Ionic CLI: 5.14.16
- Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 4.11.13
- @angular/cli: 8.1.3

Comment: try reinstalling ionic or better to downgrade ionic CLI version by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer.  My codebase was in a directory that was being backed up to the cloud (Dropbox).  Whenever files were being synced with the cloud this was triggering the live reloading functionality for some reason.  Taking the codebase outside of a directory that was being backed up to the cloud solved this.